# Rails Polymorphic index

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am looking into Rails Polymorphic Column such as 'likable' for multiple Models that can be "liked". 
ie. a Post Model has
`has_many :likes, as: :likable`

The table `likes` needs a `likable_id` (an integer) and a `likable_type`(a string)

As opposed to using this polymorphic design at all. 
Wouldn't it be more optimal for speed and memory to instead use a non polymorphic field in `like`

ie. the schema for `like` would be

```
t.integer  "post_id"
t.integer  "comment_id"
t.integer  "etc_id"
```

in this case you also get the added benefit of each column being indexed into the appropriate db table

ie.

```
t.index ["post_id"], name: "index_likes_on_post_id", using: :btree
```

As far as I can tell the polymorphic design only provides the benefit of being "cleaner" and more OO but on the downside does reduce optimization.

A string will take up more space especially if the table something like `likes` grows exponentially.

And it will be slower to compare ints vs strings as well as no index on the related tables.

So my question is why should anyone use this feature?

Comment: I am not sure but if it exists it has probably been test proofed in terms of performance. I use a polymorphic association for chat rooms applied to different models. The messageable model does hold some data. In your case, likes have no data, it's just an incrementor. There are probably better solutions than the ones you mention. Also you have to record the user who have liked. So that he can unlike if he wants. The likeability feature is more complex than we think and there are probably threads out there explaining different techniques.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid a polymorphic index you either need to break out your "likes" into individual association tables, such as `post_likes` and `comment_likes`, or try to combine those tables together somehow using Single Table Inheritance (STI) where the relationship is always between one table and another.

Adding a whole heap of columns clutters up your "likes" table and confuses its purpose. You don't want fan-out associations like that, it just makes a mess of things, especially because you want your join tables to have `NOT NULL` properties and a `UNIQUE` constraint on the two key columns.

Always strive to do the simplest thing that works, *especially* at small scales. If you need to ramp this up to handle billions of likes you'll have a better sense of usage patterns, pain points in terms of read/write activity, and will already have ideas on how to handle more records. You may find you need to shard it, spread things out horizontally, or perhaps use table partitioning. You may also find that you can use a NoSQL database to handle the data better, but you don't know because you can't predict the future.

I'd strongly advise using a polymorphic association for now with a simple index and see how that goes. If you're concerned, load it up with millions of rows of data to see how it performs. I think you'll be surprised. I've seen systems like this handle hundreds of millions of records without skipping a beat, even when running on very modest hardware.